# Mapping circles in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I have the following two circles in the complex plane, $z=x+iy$, which bound a region, $R$. The equations for the circles are given as follows:
$$x^2+(y−1)^2=1 \\ x^2+(y−2)^2=4 $$
That is, I believe, the equations of the circles can be written in complex form as: $$ ∣z-ia∣^2  = r^2 $$
I want to map the above region using the following complex function: 
$$W=\big\{w=e^{\frac{4π}{z}}:w∈R\big\}$$
And, being a beginner, I have no idea  where to start. Any recommended reading or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does $z=x+iyz=x+iy$ mean?

Comment: I assume that was a mistake that has been rectified. Apologies

Comment: @MiuM $a=1,r=1$ and $a=2,r=2$ respectively

Comment: Try to see where the boundary circles go and then figure out which is the region. Parametrizing these circles may help.

Comment: @MiuM: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650797/conformal-mapping-is-this-correct

Comment: The complex form of the circle equation is $|z-center| = radius$.